# Adding bootstrap elements to asp textbox

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

I'm fairly new in asp.net, and I am more proficient at building html/php websites.I am trying to add twitter bootstrap to my textboxes. My current textbox shows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="250px" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

And the input that I designed using html is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username">
```

How do I put all the classes of my textbox to my asp textbox, and would it take effect in a similar way html elements work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put these classes in `asp textbox` using `CssClass` as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-lg" 
    Width="250px" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Basically when you create a control `asp control` it render as a html control on the browser.
So in the browser you will see the same.

There may be difference in the `id` and the `name` of the control. As they are generated depending on the controls like `master page` and `user controls`.

Though you have different `ClientIdMode` in asp.net to overcome this issue.
MSDN for the same is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-lg" 
    Width="250px" TabIndex="1" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Can be added more attributes inside ASP tag, but must have the attribute="value" structure.